# Why am I getting duplicate entry on primary key when my input isn't even equal to the warning?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I am using a mysql data base to store students. There is a student ID as primary key, and for some reason whenever I try to add another student to the table using a different student ID, I get an error that says the following:

```
Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I am not sure why this is happening with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO students (studentID, firstName, lastName, email, username) VALUES (12341234123, 'first', 'last', 'email', 'user');
```

My table currently looks like the following:
[image]

Here is some table details:

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `studentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`studentID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am very confused ...

Comment: INT has a maximum value of 2147483647 and 12341234123 is greater, so it gets truncated down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer will take 4 Bytes (4 * 8 = 32 bits) of storage, hence will take values in the range 2^32 - 1 = 4294967295 (unsigned value) or +/-(2^31 - 1)= -2147483647 to 2147483647 values.

The value you gave is 12341234123  which is greater than the max value. So it will get truncated to the max value.

You can fix this either by changing the StudentId to a smaller number or by changing the type to BigInt if value change is not possible

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html